# What is the origin for the name "partition function" given to $Z = \sum e^{-\beta E_i}$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, history, partition-function

Does anyone know why is the function  $Z  = \sum e^{-\beta E_i}$ called ["partition function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29)?

For example, does it have a connection to the mathematical term "partition of $A$" which is a representation of the set $A$ as a disjoint union of it's subsets  (and defines an equivalence relation over $A$)?

**EDIT:** The explanation below and the explanation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37617/why-is-the-partition-function-called-partition-function) indeed almost give me a full answer. I just want to be sure:
We are divding the whole quantity be it's energy states and **not** by it's particles. This means that a class in a partition can have lots of particles and can be related to one energy state exactly. And we have to know the distribution function of the particles in the system.
Am I right?
or mayby every particle has it's own distribution?

Comment: *This is the reason for calling Z the "partition function": it encodes how the probabilities are partitioned among the different microstates, based on their individual energies.* From [Wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)#Meaning_and_significance). I have to say that this "explanation" does not satisfy me completely, though...

Comment: @valerio92  So, each probability defines a different sate of the sysrem, and under this state the particles are arranged in sets where each set contains all particles with a specific energy $E_i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is appropriate to call $Z$,

$$Z=\sum_{i \in \, \mathrm{states}}\exp \left( -\beta E_i\right)$$

the *partition* function as it describes how probabilities are distributed amongst all the states with energies $E_0, E_1$, and so forth. To see this, note that the expected value of a property $Q$ is,
$$\langle Q \rangle = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{i \in \, \mathrm{states}}Q_i\exp \left( -\beta E_i\right).$$

This is analogous to the fact that in probability, for a discrete variable $X$ which can take values $\{x_i\}$ the expected value is,

$$\langle X \rangle = \sum_{i} x_i p_i$$

for a normalised distribution $\sum_i p_i = 1$, with probabilities $p_i$ for each value $x_i$. Thus the partition function provides an appropriate weight for each state.

It is denoted by $Z$ after the German word, *Zustandssumme* which roughly translates to a sum over states, which is what we are instructed to do,$\sum_{i \in \, \mathrm{states}}$, to obtain it.

Comment: So, the partition is a partition of a distribution into all of it's energy states?

Comment: @user135172 The partition function provides a partition of the respective probabilities of the states of a system, but it is also more than that. For example, the partition function in a quantum field theory can be seen to be the generator of its correlation functions. It is quite a multi-faceted object.

Comment: @JamalS The answer does not address the question, which is about the *origin* of the term.  Same for the [duplicate question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37617/why-is-the-partition-function-called-partition-function).  I know what the partition function is, but I am still looking for an authoritative source about the origin of the term.